# I have just formatted numbers to appear with commas but now my calculator doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, calculator

I am building a calculator, which I have previously asked questions on, see previous link: [Building an interest rate calculator, however it won't produce figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44685119/building-an-interest-rate-calculator-however-it-wont-produce-figure)

I want some fields to appear with commas when entered, I found some code on here and it seems to work with the formatting however now the calculations just return NaN.

Any ideas why adding commas would stop it from working?

Here's the code I used to add the commas and the code for the calculator is on the previous link:

HTML:

```
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 form-body form-group">
                <h2 class="form-heading">Find out how much your mortgage will cost</h2>
                <div class="row text-muted">
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 calc-input">
                        <h3>Purchase Price</h3>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">£</span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control comma" id="pp" placeholder="150,000" onchange="depositValue()">
                        </div>
                        <h3>Deposit</h3>
                        <div class="row text-muted">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="percent" placeholder="10" onchange="depositValue()">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">£</span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control comma" id="dp" placeholder="15,000" onchange="depositPercent()">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <h3>Mortgage Term</h3>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mt" placeholder="25">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">Years</span>
                        </div>
                        <h3>Interest Rate</h3>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ir" placeholder="4">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 text-center">
                        <h3>Estimated Monthly Payment:</h3>
                        <p id="result"></p>
                        </div>   
                </div>
                <div class="row text-muted">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 text-center">
                        <button class="btn btn-cta" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Calculator JS:

```
    function calculate() {
var pp = document.getElementById("pp").value;
var dp = document.getElementById("dp").value;
var mt = document.getElementById("mt").value;
var ir = document.getElementById("ir").value;
var result = document.getElementById("result");

var la = parseInt(pp.replace(/,/g, ""), 10) - parseInt(dp.replace(/,/g, ""), 10);
var intRate = (ir/100)/12;
var months = mt * 12;

var monthlyPayment = ((((la*intRate)/(1-Math.pow(1+intRate,(-1*months)))*100)/100).toFixed(2));

result.innerHTML = "£" + monthlyPayment.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }

    function depositValue() {
    var pp = document.getElementById("pp").value;
    var percent = document.getElementById("percent").value;
    var dp = document.getElementById("dp");

    var dpValue = (parseInt(percent.replace(/,/g, ""), 10) / 100) * parseInt(pp.replace(/,/g, ""), 10);

    dp.value = dpValue;
    }

    function depositPercent() {
    var pp = document.getElementById("pp").value;
    var dp = document.getElementById("dp").value;
    var percent = document.getElementById("percent");

    var dpPercent = (parseInt(dp.replace(/,/g, ""), 10) / parseInt(pp.replace(/,/g, ""), 10) * 100).toFixed(0);

    percent.value = dpPercent;
    }
```

Comma JS (in another file):

```
    $('input.comma').keyup(function(event) {

    // skip for arrow keys
    if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

    // format number
    $(this).val(function(index, value) {
    return value
    .replace(/\D/g, "")
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
    ;
    });
    });
```

Comment: Because strings with commas can't be automatically coerced to number type when mathematical operations are used on them . You need to convert those strings to number manually yourself first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment you add the commas, it's no longer a number, but a string. When you do your calculations you'll have to account for that by stripping them out before processing.

Comment: Thank you. Any advice or example of how to get rid of the commas before the the calculation takes place?

Comment: Depends on how your code is structured. The simplest thing would be to replace the comma in the calculation function with a `replace`. You'll have to use `parseInt` as well... For example: `var n3 = parseInt(n1.replace(/,/g, ""), 10) + parseInt(n2.replace(/,/g, ""), 10);` --where `n1` and `n2` are variables will commas. If you don't mind purists screaming at you, you can also extend the String prototype and create a "normalizeNumber" function or something so you can just call `n1.normalizeNumber()` and try to pack everything into that function. You have options.

Comment: Awesome! I've managed to do it with the (parseInt) method. The only thing is now that something else doesn't work. Because I want some figures to show with commas after the calculation I added var.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") but it's just not working now at all, not even a NaN.

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle for this app? Otherwise, I'd just be guessing.

Comment: For some reason the fiddle wouldn't work. I've added the code into my question above.

Comment: I'm not sure what data you are using, but I was able to get it working. I've uploaded the files I used [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AMXbi5E9HRsKst1Q), along with a screenshot of my data. There are some instance where if you perform an illegal mathematical operation you will get `NaN`. For example, `0 / 0` can cause this. You might just have to put better error handling in there to account for illegal operations.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help on this, appreciate it!